# how to make code in a html file responsive

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design, pre

I am creating a responsive html newsletter e-mail. Part of that e-mail needs to display code, with an image next to it. Currently I have this code for it but it is not responsive. Is there a way to make it responsive without using media queries?

```
<tr>
    <td width="30px"></td>
    <td style="padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;font-size:12px;color:#999999; text-align:left; border: solid #999999 1px; line-height: 1.1em;">
           <pre><code>

             &lt;a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://?utm_source%
            dium%3Dexpert%2520badge%26utm_campaign%3Dexpert%
            2520badge&sa=D&usg=ALhdy2-CNQcMIQSH8F4dPpFoAup9
            wUpBpA" rel="nofollow"&gt;&lt;img src="/" alt="blur
            "width="125px" height="125px"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
          </code></pre>
  </td>
 <td style="padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;">
      <a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http:/t%2520badge&sa=D&usg=ALhdy2-QcMIQSH8F4dPpFoAup9wUpBpA" rel="nofollow"><img src="" alt="" width="125px" height="125px"></a>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Not really, responsive is pretty much about using media queries. What is it exactly you want to do?

Comment: what about just making the text fit within its content box, so the smaller the width the the bigger the height?

Comment: `width: 100%; height: auto;` ?

Comment: Actually, you could use percentages to make things responsive. Its a bit trickier, but if you use `width: 100%` and `max-width: 500px`, then you technically have a responsive box. Tough for emails though, as outlook will downright **mangle** them.

Comment: If you are not comfortable with media queries, there are online services that automatically do it for you. How well these services work is dependant on the complexity of your site. Search 'online responsive converter' or something similar. Though I do highly recommend learning media queries as they aren't all that complicated at all.

Comment: will give the width and height a go, as for media queries I know how to sue them but many e-mail clients refuse them unfortunately.

Comment: Just tried using the width % method and the box seems to be fixed and doesn't respond to it.

Comment: The box will fit the width of it's parent, if you resize it, it should change

Comment: even if the parent is a <td> > ?

Comment: i think whats causing the the text not to resize is the fact that it's code and theres not too much spacing in between elements? So the longest part of the code is the url, therefore it will be as long as the url I'm guessing?

Comment: any other suggestions? @AndyHolmes :)